# How to setup to use local time in cron schedule?

Tags: cron

Cron by default uses UTC time zone. How to set it up to use Local time (say CST) in the cron expression (for cron schedule).

Answer (score 12):

You can set your system's time zone to the intended time zone and then state the time for that zone in the cron job:

```
sudo timedatectl set-timezone America/New_York
```

and confirm typing `timedatectl`, or do

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
```

After changing the time zone, make sure to restart cron:

```
sudo service cron restart
```

Cron job:

```
30 5 * * * echo "run at half past 5" >> ~/logfile.log 2>&1
```

Comment: I did set the timezone but did not restart the cron, and sure enough the job didn't run at the time I was expecting. Thank you @rndmGuy for the point about restarting cron.

Answer (score -3):

Cron doesn't care about time zone.  It compares the current time to the cron string and executes the job if they match.

Comment: No! That is not true.

Comment: If you know the answer then why did you ask the question?  Check out https://crontab.guru and you'll see no reference to time zones.  There is a workaround, however.  Look for CRON_TZ in https://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab

Comment: No, I don't know the answer. I just know that, I did setup an alert to run at 12:05AM but it did run at 5:05PM. So... But thanks for sharing the link, it helps me understand it more.